# Sequences of measurable sets and Fubini's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Let $\Omega_n\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a sequence of bounded measurable sets such that $\mathcal{L}(\Omega_h) \to 0$. Does then $x$ $\mathcal{L}^1$-a.e. the following hold?

$$\lim_{h\to \infty} \mathcal{L}^{n-1}((\Omega_h)_{x})=0,$$
where $(E_h)_x=\{y\in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}|~ (y,x)\in \Omega_h \}$.

My idea is to use Fubinis theorem:

$$0=\lim_{h\to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathcal{L}^{n-1}((\Omega_h)_x) \, dx$$
    However I don't know how to take the limit inside the integral.

I thought about using the dominated convergence theorem with $\mathcal{L}^{n-1}(\bigcup_h \Omega_h)_x$, but I was not able to show that $\bigcup_h \Omega_h$ has finite measure.

Comment: By Fatou's lemma, $\liminf_h\mathcal L^{n-1}((\Omega_h)_x)=0$ for a.e. $x$. This would be enough if $h\mapsto \Omega_h$ were monotone non-increasing.

Comment: Do you mean with $h\mapsto \Omega_h$ non-increasing that $h\mapsto \mathcal{L}(\Omega_h)$ is non-increasing?
As $\mathcal{L}(\Omega_h)\to 0$, this holds at least for a subsequence. Is this enough?

Comment: I mean that with $h\mapsto\Omega_h$ monotone, $\lim_h\mathcal L^{n-1}((\Omega_h)_x)$ exists for every $x$ and coincides with $\liminf_h\mathcal L^{n-1}((\Omega_h)_x)$. It follows that $\lim_h\mathcal L^{n-1}((\Omega_h)_x)=0$ for a.e. $x$.